# Send data Android Studio to PHP crash (ampersand)

Tags: java, php, android

Cannot send complete string in Android Studio:

```
json_sales = "Client: blabla & net...."
HttpRequest req = null;
JSONArray products = null;
JSONObject json = null;
json_sales = json_sales.replace("\n", " ");

HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("data", json_sales);
params.put("tipo", "vd");

String l_resp = "";
try {
    req = new HttpRequest(server + "/importallsalses.php");
    l_resp = req.prepare(HttpRequest.Method.POST).withData(params).sendAndReadString();
} ...
```

file: importallsalses.php

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    include "adodb5/adodb.inc.php";

    $data=$_POST["data"];
    $tipo=$_POST["tipo"];
    echo $data;
?>
```

Result - echo: "Client: blabla"

My problem is ampersand. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried URL encoding the &?

Comment: You should encode the data you're sending: `json_sales = URLEncoder.encode(json_sales, "utf-8");`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not encoding the ampersand `&` symbol before sending it.

Using Javas `URLEncoder` is likely your friend here. Changing your `params.put()` assignment to the below should solve it:

`params.put("data", URLEncoder.encode(json_sales, "utf-8"));`